# Duality of a linear programming problem in matrix form?

Tags: matrices, linear-programming, duality-theorems

trying to find the duality of the LP problem in matrix/vector form:

min c<sub>1</sub><sup>T</sup>x<sub>1</sub> + c<sub>2</sub><sup>T</sup>x<sub>2</sub>
s.t.    A<sub>1</sub>x<sub>1</sub> + A<sub>2</sub>x<sub>2</sub> = b
x<sub>1</sub>>= 0

I get that the duality of like

min c<sup>T</sup>x
s.t. Ax = b
x>=0

would be

max b<sup>T</sup>u
s.t. A<sup>T</sup>u <= c

but I'm not really sure how the addition of 2 different matrices would affect the constraints or how to visualize this problem? I think the objective would still be max b<sup>T</sup>u but I am not sure?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are single variables. Then the dual program is

$\texttt{max} \ \ b^Tu$

$A_1^T u\leq c_1$

$A_2^T u=c_2$

The number of variables ($u_i$) depends on the dimension of vector $\mathbf b$.

Comment: would you explain me how $\lambda^T b$ become $b^T \lambda$? would you use inner product or any other formula?